# React css not loading properly

Tags: css, reactjs

I used create-react-app to create a very simple app. But the css is not working for me. Here's my code

```
# Test.css
.h1 {
    color: white;
}

# Test.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './Test.css';

class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className={styles.h1}>Test!</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default Test;
```

The color of my h1 is still black not white. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please see my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467036/how-inject-css-in-component-react/45473762#45473762

Comment: Can you paste your webpack config as well ? Especially the `module` part

Comment: I don't have a webpack config.. Still new to react. When I create-react-app it didn't give me one. So is one webpack config required to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Test.css
.h1 {
    color: white;
}

# Test.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './Test.css';

class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className={styles.h1}>Test!</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default Test;

In the project that I’m adding CSS Modules to we already have one loader defined for our JavaScript:

module: {
  loaders: [{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
    include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
  }`enter code here`
}
webpack config
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'style-loader'
}, {
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'css-loader',
  query: {
    modules: true,
    localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
  }
}
```